# Does The Key use regular 'ctrl' keys on the keyboard?

Tags: discussion, blog, fun, april-fools

I just realized that there seems to be a confusion about the Key.

[image]

Get this:

- Normal computers use 'ctrl + c' (or 'cmd + c') and 'ctrl + v' (or 'cmd + v') for copying and pasting respectively.
- On the Key, there are three buttons as follows :-

1. One that resembles a Stack Overflow logo
2. A big letter 'C'
3. A big letter 'V'

My question is, How do you use the Key to copy and paste?

Is it like you press the logo with 'C' and 'V', use your very own 'ctrl or 'cmd' button for the combinations..... or what?

Comment: Another doubt (possibly another question entirely) - Does the logo (when pressed) take you to Stack Overflow???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does the logo (when pressed) take you to Stack Overflow???

Yes, it does. The Key does not yet have the capability to detect *when* you want to launch Stack Overflow. This might work in future versions though.

> Is it like you press the logo with 'C' and 'V'

The device is designed for optimal user experience. Such important and often used actions should not rely on having two fingers free, so just pressing a single button is sufficient. It will automagically add the right modifier key, depending on your operating system. It's even smart enough to work together with any [keymappers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) you might have configured.

Comment: This answer is very, very incorrect: https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1377615767731048452 clearly shows you need two fingers to copy paste.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell that's the prototype, they must have improved it meanwhile